# How do I put 's after a quoted name?

Tags: punctuation

The city "Big Apple"'s real name is New York.

Is that correct?

I know there are many other ways to say it but what if I need to put an `'s` after a quoted name?

Comment: It may be *technically* correct, but I can't think of anybody who would write it that way. The quotation mark followed immediately by an apostrophe is simply too confusing. One of the other ways you refer to would be used instead. (Plus, unless it actually *is* a quote, you shouldn't normally use quotation marks.) Note, too, that *the city "Big Apple"* sounds strange. It should either be *the city called the "Big Apple"* or just *the "Big Apple."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good question, but I expect the most common answer is: "You don't".

There are very few cases where you *have to* express a sentence in a particular way.  If the possessive would be awkward, rephrase:

> It's called "The Big Apple", but the city's real name is New York.

[From the Chicago Manual of Style:](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/quotation-marks-and-apostrophe-s/)

> . . . A term enclosed in quotation marks . . . should never be made into a possessive. 7.30

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks for the link to the dailywritingtips :P

Comment: Yup... A truly frustrating circumstance for any writer or proofreader. When typographical convention prevents you from writing what's perfectly fine orally (and not because it's informal!).

Comment: https://www.talemed.com/city/new-york-city-ny/ In this post, I found the following expression: `The city’s 5 boroughs sit where the Hudson River meets the Atlantic Ocean, with the island borough of Manhattan at the “Big Apple’s” core.`. I am quite curious whether it's correctly written.

Comment: @AGamePlayer  It's grammatical, but still awkward in my opinion.  I would have written, *.... at the core of the "Big Apple"* to avoid the troublesome possessive.